# Usage of Union in OOP

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unions

Unions can be used as a type just like a class and structure(with some restrictions).It can have member functions. It can be used as an OOP construct.

As I understand unions were just imported in to C++ to maintain backward compatibility with C.
In all these years of programming I have never used an union like I would use an class or a structure as an OOP construct.

Is there any practical usage of Union as an OOP construct(not just as an data type) or it is just some vestigial part of the language that is never useful?

---

**EDIT:**
The standard definitely allows union to act as an OOP construct. It allows for member functions in unions. Following code compiles and works and is standard compliant:

```
union A
{
    int a;
    int k;

    void doSomething(){}

};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    int i = obj.a;
    obj.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the standard allow member functions in an union if it is not supposed to act as an OOP construct?
Please post answers with specific reasoning and please refrain from posting an answer *I don't think so*, without a good reasoning of *why?*

Comment: What do you consider to be an object oriented concept in your code sample?

Comment: @stefanbachert: Please do not bother about me being perceived *less friendly* or my *social competence* and limit your comments and answers to the Q being asked only. I guess your downvote stems from the fact that your answer didn't add anything meaningful and I pointed that out instead of downvoting it.. *my bad!* What do i consider OOP concept? Unions do provide *Encapsulation* and *Abstraction*.

Comment: You repeat to be unfriendly. However, what does your sample encapsulate and abstract?

Comment: @stefanbachert: I already answered you in the previous comment and do not wish to repeat it again.So I give up and Just so you know, I don't expect any worthwhile answer from you because your comments stem from more of an revenge feeling than anything actually meaningful.

Comment: "Why does the standard allow member functions" Answer to thsi question requires telepath or fortune teller. I'd suggest to stick with "because it was designed to work this way".

Comment: You don't answer the question WHAT does an union encapsulate or abstract. I do see nothing. If someone else sees an aspect, please comment

Comment: @SigTerm: There are some users here who have been long standing members of the standards committee they can certainly add a perspective here, also the Q is marked with an *Language-lawyer* tag .The tag is in existence for questions like these.So please let the ones who can answer it have an chance to answer it.

Comment: @Als: "There are some users" Then the answer will be personal opinion. "So please let" The question is still here, ans if you're one of those "users", you can answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, a union is not an OO construct.

The single most important feature of OO is polymorphism, but unions cannot participate in a inheritance relationship (cannot be a base of a different type, cannot have bases itself) or have virtual functions. The only purpose of an union is to provide a data type, not an *object*.

Comment: Why is it allowed to have member functions and access specifiers? So in that sense, It does in some sense provide Encapsulation, which is an OOP construct.

Comment: *Why not*, it makes sense to provide *constructors* as the constructor can be used to initialize the object. Because the standard allows the use of the initial members that are common to all of the enum members, there can be functions that apply on the union as a whole --because they can be applied no matter what the active member is. Consider the common motivating example of reading messages in wire format, the header will be the same, so you can just create your union and ask for what the message length or message type are (if those are part of the common header to all messages)

Comment: The issue at hand is while you consider that to be OO, I don't. Having constructors and members are not two features that provide OO. Rather inheritance and polymorphism are, and unions cannot be involved in either (directly, they can indirectly if the union is a member of a different type)

Comment: I certainly agree to your assessment that the difference of opinion here is because I consider that(encapsulation) to be an OO while you don't.I just find it strange that one of the OO concept is allowed while others were not and that stems from the fact that unions could very well have lived and been as much useful without the member functions so why the mixing of concepts.

Comment: @Als: You can have encapsulation and data hiding in C, and that does not make it OO. Consider all libraries that provide *handles*, including `open()` that returns an `int` that can later be used in other functions. The exact data structure of a file descriptor completely opaque to user code in the most effective use of data hiding you can get, much more than `private` access specifiers. Just because one of the requirements for OO is present, it does not mean that OO is present.

Comment: +1 For your answer and I wish I could add a few more +1's for your counter arguments in the comments.This will be my accepted answer unless someone comes up with an better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

My personal view is "no".

Historically, C has allowed developers low-level access to the host system, accessing memory in very flexible ways. By providing a construct to treat the same area of memory as different data types, this flexibility was made even easier.

But it's hard to see how this can be classified as any type of object-oriented construct.

Comment: It is certainly [allowed](http://ideone.com/Wz4Xp) to act as an type of object oriented construct. The question is does it have any practical usage?

Comment: It can certainly be used within object-oriented constructs. And it certainly has practical usage. But my point was that I don't see it useful for promoting OOP design. It's a raw construct which requires outside understanding of the memory layout to use correctly. In my view, this runs counter to OOP principals, where more details are handled internally within a class.

Comment: In that case my question is: *Why does the standard allow member functions in an union if it is not supposed to act as an OOP construct?*

Comment: Maybe the real question is: Is there a reason to disallow member function on unions? C++ never says it intends to support OO only

Comment: @Als: What is your definition of *OOP construct*. I, myself, don't consider that the standard allows unions to be used as an OO construct. In my definition of OO, inheritance and polymorphism are the two most important features, and unions cannot participate in either.

Answer (score 1):

I think **no**.

**unions** have nothing to do with **object orientation**.

C++ never says it intends to support OO only. C++ supports from beginning **multiple paradigm** (meanwhile: procedural, functional, generative, object oriented)

The C++ 11 supports "**unrestricted unions**" but I do no see any usage from the OO perspective

Depending on authors **object orientation** requires the following issues:

- identity
- inheritance / generalism
- polymorphy
- encapsulation

In case of **unions** the first issue is valid. 
An union could be identified (by its address for example)

There is NO concept of **inheritance** available for unions.

One could argue data is polymorph in a union, but this interpretation is far from what oo considers to be polymorph.
A union could not have virtual function which would be nearly useless without inheritance.
And it would break the memory layout.

There is **encapsulation** in an union.
However, due to limitations I do not expect useful applications for this case.
If any I would appreciate a link

With this set of features I would consider "abstract data type" (ADA) as to be the right term.

Comment: *There is NO encapsulation in a union. Any member is public. No change to hide implementation details.* is wrong & misleading, One can always use access specifiers in unions and [achieve the very same encapsulation that a class provides](http://ideone.com/Zga1P).

Comment: Accepted, I will change the answer

Comment: Now that you realize that union supports atleast one(even though the less important ones of) OO paradigm, perhaps you can relate more to the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good practice, but suppose you could make a strong guarantee that only one field would be active:

```
class multi_type {
private:
    bool unit_is_float;
    union {
        float float_member;
        int int_member;
    };
public:
    multi_type(bool is_float) : unit_is_float(is_float) {}
    bool isFloat() { return unit_is_float; }
    bool isInt() { return !unit_is_float; }
    float& getFloat() {
        if (!isFloat()) throw std::logic_error("not a float");
        return float_member;
    }
    int& getInt() {
        if (!isInt()) throw std::logic_error("not an int");
        return int_member;
    }
};
```

Formatted to be concise, not pretty.

A valid application might be in some sort of parsing library where the language to be parsed can have different types of tokens which can only be determined at run-time.  It's an alternative to using void*s.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> C++ union is a limited form of the class type. It can contain access
>   specifiers (public, protected, private), member data, and member
>   functions, including constructors and destructors. It cannot contain
>   virtual functions or static data members. It cannot be used as a base
>   class, nor can it have base classes. Default access of members in a
>   union is public.

It is even possible to template unions (see e.g. [Templates - The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003YL3OYG)). In that sense, unions provide almost identical *degree* of **encapsulation**.

All those syntactic constraints notwithstanding, unions do fill a small hole in ways to break the C++ type system. Consider these loose correspondences:

```
class/struct with virtual functions    <--> dynamic_cast
class/struct without virtual functions <--> static_cast
union                                  <--> reinterpret_cast
```

**Polymorphism** is all about breaking the type system in a safe and controlled manner. Classes and structs break the type system **in time**. With virtual functions, we can break the type system at run-time; without virtual functions, we can do it at compile-time (especially with templates). Unions on the other hand, can break the type system **in place**. Note that polymorphism and encapsulation go hand in hand: whatever is liable to change is hidden from the user (either through vtables, compile-time lookups or data reinterpretation).

Whether this is enough to label unions as being part of the OO style of programming, seems a matter of taste to me.

Answer (score 0):

As a low level construct a union is then useful if your data has different interpretations and types based on context. In this sense, it helps you keep your objects smaller than if you keep different fields which cannot exist concurrently.

Is that a valid concern for OOP? Kind of, I guess...

--

One hack people do with them is access different bytes with different names (typical examples is to have a union of 4 bytes r,g,b,a and one 32 bit integer color), but this is potentially dangerous https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582389/278842.

Comment: This does not answer the question.it provides useful information but it is not related to the Q being asked.

Comment: Expanded, but I was going more for the part his question where he asks "or it is just some vestigial part of the language that is never useful?"

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is dangerous about using a union to reinterpret an int as separate bytes? Endianness? EDIT: nevermind, didn't notice the link at first.