# Set specific byte in DWORD

Tags: c++

How i can set specific byte in 4 bytes length DWORD variable?

```
DWORD color_argb;
unsigned char a = 11; // first byte
unsigned char r = 22; // second byte
unsigned char g = 33; // third byte
unsigned char b = 44; // fouth byte
```

**zumalifeguard**, if I understand you correctly - i can use next macroses:

```
#define SET_COLOR_A(color, a) color |= (a << 24)
#define SET_COLOR_R(color, r) color |= (r << 16)
#define SET_COLOR_G(color, g) color |= (g << 8)
#define SET_COLOR_B(color, b) color |= (b << 0)
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert from DWORD RGBA to ints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582372/how-can-i-convert-from-dword-rgba-to-ints)

Comment: If this is the Win32 API, three of them are done for you with the `RGB` macro.

Comment: i. e. i can do this by macro like this: `#define SET_COLOR_A(a) a << 24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these macros instead:

```
#define SET_COLOR_A(color, a) color = (DWORD(color) & 0x00FFFFFF) | ((DWORD(a) & 0xFF) << 24)
#define SET_COLOR_R(color, r) color = (DWORD(color) & 0xFF00FFFF) | ((DWORD(r) & 0xFF) << 16)
#define SET_COLOR_G(color, g) color = (DWORD(color) & 0xFFFF00FF) | ((DWORD(g) & 0xFF) << 8)
#define SET_COLOR_B(color, b) color = (DWORD(color) & 0xFFFFFF00) | (DWORD(b) & 0xFF)
```

The important thing is to **preserve existing bits** that are not being manipulated, while **removing existing bits** that are being replaced.  Simply `OR`'ing the new bits is not enough if there are already bits present in the location being assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

```
DWORD color_argb;
unsigned char a = 11; // first byte
unsigned char r = 22; // second byte
unsigned char g = 33; // third byte
unsigned char b = 44; // fouth byte

color_argb = 0;
int byte_number; // first byte = 1, second byte = 2, etc.

// Set first byte to a;
byte_number = 1;
color_argb |= ( a << (8 * (4 - byte_number) ) );

// Set first byte to a;
byte_number = 2;
color_argb |= ( b << (8 * (4 - byte_number) ) ); 

// Set first byte to a;
byte_number = 3;
color_argb |= ( c << (8 * (4 - byte_number) ) ); 

// Set first byte to a;
byte_number = 4;
color_argb |= ( d << (8 * (4 - byte_number) ) );
```